# Global ItemLoader - Share among multiplespiders

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm fairly new to Scrapy/Python.

I want to crawl several websites but I'll get only three items from each website "date" "cota" and "name" which are updated daily and have always the same xpath

After scraping all that, I want export to a csv file, but with my code I get the 
following formatting

[image]

But I would like to have something like this

[image]

I asked specifically about sharing the same ItemLoader among multiple spiders because that's what came to mind, but I'm open to other alternatives.

That's the script that I have so far for two websites, I'll add more spiders later on:

By the way, with the code like that, is there any chance of getting the values mixed up given that scrapy is asynchronous?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class fundo(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    cota = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()

class ModalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'modal'
    allowed_domains = ['modalasset.com.br']
    start_urls = ['http://modalasset.com.br/cotas-diarias/']

    def parse(self, response):

        l = ItemLoader(item=fundo(),response=response)

        name = response.xpath("//tr[@class='row-6 even']/td/a/text()").extract_first()
        date = response.xpath("//tr[@class='row-6 even']/td/text()")[0].extract()
        cota = response.xpath("//tr[@class='row-6 even']/td/text()")[1].extract()


        l.add_value('name', name)
        l.add_value('date', date)
        l.add_value('cota', cota)

        return l.load_item()

class KapitaloSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kapitalo'
    allowed_domains = ['kapitalo.com.br/relatorios.']
    start_urls = ['http://kapitalo.com.br/relatorios.html']

    def parse(self, response):

        l = ItemLoader(item=fundo(),response=response)

        name = response.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']")[1].xpath("td//text()")[0].extract()
        date = response.xpath("//*[@class='event layout_full block bygone']/h2/text()")[0].extract()
        date = date.replace(' Cotas do Dia: ','')
        cota = response.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']")[1].xpath("td//text()")[1].extract()

        l.add_value('name', name)
        l.add_value('date', date)
        l.add_value('cota', cota)

        return l.load_item()


process = CrawlerProcess({
'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
'FEED_URI': 'result.csv'
})
process.crawl(ModalSpider)
process.crawl(KapitaloSpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

Another way I was trying was with the following code, but add_value is substituing the old value in the ItemLoader, couldn't figure out why.
So it's only returning the values from the last website.
I'd rather use the first code because it allowes me to use different kinds of spiders and for one of the websites I'll probably need to use Selenium.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.http import Request

class FundoItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()
    cota = scrapy.Field()

class RankingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Ranking'
    allowed_domains = ['modalasset.com.br',
                        'kapitalo.com.br'
                        ]
    start_urls = ['http://modalasset.com.br/cotas-diarias/']

    def parse(self, response):

        l = ItemLoader(item=FundoItem(),response=response)

        name = response.xpath("//tr[@class='row-6 even']/td/a/text()").extract_first()
        date = response.xpath("//tr[@class='row-6 even']/td/text()")[0].extract()
        cota = response.xpath("//tr[@class='row-6 even']/td/text()")[1].extract()

        #item['name'] = name
        #item['date'] = date
        #item['cota'] = cota

        l.add_value('name', name)
        l.add_value('date', date)
        l.add_value('cota', cota)


        yield Request(url = "http://kapitalo.com.br/relatorios.html",
                        callback = self.parse_2,
                        meta={'item':l.load_item()})


    def parse_2 (self,response):

        name = response.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']")[1].xpath("td//text()")[0].extract()
        date = response.xpath("//*[@class='event layout_full block bygone']/h2/text()")[0].extract()
        date = date.replace(' Cotas do Dia: ','')
        cota = response.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']")[1].xpath("td//text()")[1].extract()

        l = ItemLoader(item=response.meta['item'])

        l.add_value('name', name)
        l.add_value('date', date)
        l.add_value('cota', cota)

        return l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a problem due to how windows is interpreting the newline in the csv file.
I solved by using the following code instead of FEED_EXPORT:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv',mode='a',newline='\n') as csv_file:
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerow([name,date,cota,url])
```

the `newline = '\n'` solves the issues.

The end code became:

```
#Scrapy framework
#CrawlerProcess to run multiple spiders
#csv to export
#sys,inspect to find all the classes(spiders) in this script

import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import csv
import sys, inspect
import datetime

#SPIDER DEFINITIONS

class ModalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'modal'
    allowed_domains = ['modalasset.com.br']
    start_urls = ['http://modalasset.com.br/cotas-diarias/']

    def parse(self, response):

        name = response.xpath("//tr[@class='row-6 even']/td/a/text()").extract_first()
        date = response.xpath("//tr[@class='row-6 even']/td/text()")[0].extract()
        cota = response.xpath("//tr[@class='row-6 even']/td/text()")[2].extract()

        write(name,date,cota,response.request.url)


class KapitaloSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kapitalo'
    allowed_domains = ['kapitalo.com.br/relatorios.']
    start_urls = ['http://kapitalo.com.br/relatorios.html']

    def parse(self, response):

        #Zeta FIQ FIM
        name = response.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']")[1].xpath("td//text()")[0].extract()
        date = response.xpath("//*[@class='event layout_full block bygone']/h2/text()")[0].extract()
        date = date.replace(' Cotas do Dia: ','')
        date = date.replace('.','/')
        cota = response.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']")[1].xpath("td//text()")[1].extract()

        write(name,date,cota,response.request.url)

        #Kappa FIN FIQ FIM
        name = response.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']")[0].xpath("td//text()")[0].extract()
        cota = response.xpath("//tr[@class='odd']")[0].xpath("td//text()")[1].extract()

        write(name,date,cota,response.request.url)

#write to csv file
#newline='\n' so it won't jump any lines between the entries
def write(name,date,cota,url):
    with open('test.csv',mode='a',newline='\n') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([name,date,cota,url])

def crawl():

    #create the columns in the csv file
    with open('test.csv',mode="w",newline='\n') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(['Nome do Fundo','Data','Cota do dia','URL'])

    #get all the members from the script
    #if it's a class and it's inside the main (it's a spider)
    #then it crawls
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            if obj.__module__ == '__main__':
                process.crawl(obj)

    process.start()

crawl()
```